# Update multiple rows with same id and same value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a simple update query, which somehow doesn't work. Already trying to change it for some time and compared it to other update-queries but no matter what I change, it does not function. Two rows in the same table with the same teacher_id should be updated with the same value.

Here is the query:

```php
$StatusChangeQuery = "UPDATE teachers SET status_id = $status_id WHERE teacher_id = '20'";

$pdo->query($StatusChangeQuery);
```

I know it is a really simple one, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'WHERE teacher_id = '20'' at line 1' in /var/www/xxx/html/teacher.php:225 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/xxx/html/teacher.php(225): 
PDO->query('UPDATE teachers...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/xxx/html/teacher.php on line 225
```

And the corresponding teachers rows look like:

```
+---+-------------+------------+
|id | teacher_id  | status_id  |
+---+-------------+------------+
| 1 |     20      |      1     |
| 2 |     20      |      1     |
+---+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: What's the value of `$status_id` when the error occurs?

Comment: If the teacher_id column is INT based, you would not need quotes around the '20'

Comment: Can you print $StatusChangeQuery before running query and post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest, there is probably an issue with `$status_id`.

Since you are using PDO, it is advisable to prepare your statements.

```
$smt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE teachers SET status_id=? WHERE teacher_id=?");
$smt->execute( array($status_id, 20) );
```

Comment: @ Nate B, Haymaker, cyber.sh and rybo111:Thank you guys, you were right, there was an issue with the $status_id -> I recognized it after I printed the $StatusChangeQuery. Solved it now -> I had used $_POST instead of $_GET. And I used the prepared statements now, thanks for the advice!